# Dynamically inclusion of directive in the view

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

Let's say I have the following directives:

- `myDirectiveA`
- `myDirectiveB`
- ...

and I have a variable (`module`) which can be `a` or `b`, ... I want to dynamically display the directives depending on `module`.

I know I could do

```
<div class="my-directives-a" ng-show="module == 'a'"></div>
<div class="my-directives-b" ng-show="module == 'b'"></div>
```

but this is not exactly what I want. On my project I'd like to have something like this

```
<div ng-repeat="module in modules">
  <div class="my-directive-{{ module }}" ...></div>
</div>
```

So I created this [plunker script](https://plnkr.co/edit/z63BMBJyAu1WxdjawJkE?p=preview) to check my idea but that doesn't seem to work :(

My question are: is this possible and if so how? And is this a good idea in the first place or should I try to solve my problem in a different way?

Comment: why cant you use "ng-switch" or "ng-if" it is better than "ng-show" which just changes CSS ,   "ng-switch" and "ng-if" remove it from the DOM.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch

Comment: Because I don't know how many directives I have to include and I don't want to hardcode them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to accomplish dynamic directives is through the use of $compile.

Given a directive:

```
angular.module(...)
.directive("dynamicDirective", ["$compile", function($compile) {
  return {
    scope: { dirName: "=" },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      var template = '<div class="my-directives-"' + scope.dirName + '></div>';
      directiveElem = $compile(template);
      elem.append(directiveElem);
    }
  };
}]);
```

You can use the directive as follows:

```
<div dynamic-directive dir-name="module" ng-repeat="module in modules"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks great. I'll try that later. What would happen if for example I had `<div dynamic-directive dir-name="module"></div>` and some user interaction changes `$scope.module` from `a` to `b`? Would angular automatically load the new directive or do I have to watch some property?